# SwiftUI's custom modal logic: how to present view from parent

Tags: swiftui

Coming from UIKit, I'm building my own modal navigation logic in SwiftUI, because I want custom layouts and animations. Here, I want a generic bottom sheet like so:

[image: example]

I have achieved something close with the following code:

```
enum ModalType: Equatable {
    case normal // ...
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var screen: some View {
        switch self {
        case .normal: ModalView()
            // ...
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var presentedModal: ModalType?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Present modal", action: { presentedModal = .normal }).foregroundColor(.black)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.gray)
        .modifier(ModalBottomViewModifier(item: $presentedModal) { $0.screen })
    }
}


struct ModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismissModal) private var dismissModal

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Close", action: { dismissModal() })
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 300)
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 32)
                .fill(.black.opacity(0.5))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.bottom])
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


// MARK: - Modal logic

struct ModalBottomViewModifier<Item:Equatable, V:View>: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var item: Item?
    @ViewBuilder var view: (Item) -> V
        
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            content
            
            if let item = item {
                view(item)
                    .environment(\.dismissModal, { self.item = nil })
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeOut, value: item)
    }
}

private struct ModalDismissKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: () -> Void = {}
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var dismissModal: () -> Void {
        get { self[ModalDismissKey.self] }
        set { self[ModalDismissKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to make this system reusable, so that I don't have to add the `ModalBottomViewModifier` to all my app screens. For that, I'd like to be able to apply the modifier to the button instead of the screen, just like it's possible with `fullScreenCover`:

```
Button("Present modal", action: { isPresented = true }).foregroundColor(.black)
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresented) { ModalView() }
```

This is not possible with my current solution, because the modal view will appear next to the button and not fullscreen.

How can I achieve this? Or should I be doing something different?

Comment: I believe you can just create a function that returns a view.

Comment: It is possible to do by applying modal modifier at very root level and transfer conditional control there via preference key from functional modifier (like fullScreenCover does).

Comment: @Asperi what would be the type of the preference key in this scenario ? I'm coming back to this question because of my problem in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73223144/3780788
Your solution with preference key might solve this other binding problem because it's doesn't require a UIKit bridge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using `UIKit`:

[image]

```
extension View {
    func presentModalView<Content: View, Item: Equatable>(item: Binding<Item?>, @ViewBuilder view: @escaping (Item) -> Content) -> some View {
        func present() {
            guard let itemy = item.wrappedValue else {return}
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let topMostController = self.topMostController()
                let someView = VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    view(itemy)
                        .environment(\.dismissModal, {item.wrappedValue = nil})
                }
                let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: someView)
                viewController.view?.backgroundColor = .clear
                viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
                topMostController.present(viewController, animated: true)
            }
        }
        return self.onChange(of: item.wrappedValue) { value in
            if value != nil {
                present()
            }else {
                topMostController().dismiss(animated: true)
            }
        }.onAppear {
            if item.wrappedValue != nil {
                present()
            }
        }
    }
    func topMostController() -> UIViewController {
        var topController: UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController!
        while (topController.presentedViewController != nil) {
            topController = topController.presentedViewController!
        }
        return topController
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var presentedModal: ModalType?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Present modal", action: { presentedModal = .normal }).foregroundColor(.black)
                .presentModalView(item: $presentedModal, view: {$0.screen})
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.gray)
    }
}
```